# Why isn't every open set of an affine scheme quasi-compact?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, commutative-algebra, schemes, fake-proofs

Let $X = \text{Spec }A$ be an affine scheme. We always have that $X$ is quasi-compact, although in general it is certainly not true that any open set $U \subseteq X$ is quasi-compact.

I was recently trying to show that if $Z \subseteq X$ is a closed subset, then $Z$ can be covered by a finite number of affine open sets of the form $Z \cap D(f_{i})$ with $f_{i} \in A$. In the process, I seem to have "proved" the above claim, which I know is false. Although I am not actually able to find where my mistake is, so I am clearly not understanding something properly.

Let $\mathcal{I} \subseteq A$ be the ideal defining the closed set $Z$. That is, let $Z = V(\mathcal{I})$. Without loss of generality, we can take $\mathcal{I}$ to be radical. The points of $V(\mathcal{I})$ correspond to the prime ideals of $A$ containing $\mathcal{I}$. That is, prime ideals of $A / \mathcal{I}$. Also, $A / \mathcal{I}$ is a reduced ring, and we can choose a finite number of non-unit, non-nilpotent elements which generate the unit ideal,
$$
A / \mathcal{I} = \langle \bar{g_{1}}, \bar{g_{2}}, \ldots , \bar{g_{m}}      \rangle.
$$

> But any prime $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq A$ containing $\mathcal{I}$ must
>   fail to contain at least one of the $g_{j}$, since otherwise it would
>   be sent to the unit ideal in $A / \mathcal{I}$. So the distinguished
>   open sets $\{ D(g_{j}) \}_{j}$ cover $Z$.

Now let $U$ be the complement of $Z$ in $X$. Since $U$ is open, it may be covered by a collection of distinguished open sets $\{D(f_{i}) \}_{i}$. Taking the collection of all the $D(f_{i})$ and $D(g_{j})$ together then gives a cover for $X$ with the former collection contained in $U$ and the latter collection contained in $Z$. By quasi-compactness, we can choose a finite subcollection of this combined collection, and so there must be only finitely many of the $D(f_{i})$ necessary to cover $U$.

Where exactly does this argument fail? The only place I can see it possibly may is the part I have highlighted above. Is it really true that $\mathfrak{p}$ being sent to the unit ideal means that it itself must not be proper?

Comment: There's no reason the $D(g_j)$ are contained in $Z$, right?

Comment: "...although in general it is certainly not true that any open set $U \subseteq X$ is quasi-compact." Do you know a counter-example?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I think one is provided by the spectrum of a polynomial ring in infinitely many indeterminates, $k[x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3} \ldots ]$. The infinite union of all the distinguished opens $D(x_{i})$ is surely not quasi-compact, right?

Comment: Dear Luke, this is indeed correct and is exactly the example I came up with yesterday when I read your question !

Comment: Oh, it seems like you just need an ideal of a ring that's not finitely generated? Except there's some radical ideal issue that I'm sure how to clarify. Algebraic geometry is weird.

Comment: It is extremely weird, which is why I enjoy it and want to eventually do my thesis in it, but at the moment it's kicking my ass in grad school.

Comment: * not sure how to clarify. @GeorgesElencwajg?

Comment: @Dustan: sorry, what do you want me to clarify exactly ?

Comment: Given an ideal $\mathcal I \subset A$ and generators $\{a_s\}_{s \in S}$ of $\mathcal I$, I'm guessing there isn't in general an easy way to characterize when $X-V(\mathcal I)$ isn't a finite union of $D(a_s)$'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the $D(g_j)$ are not contained in $Z$ - when you're covering $Z$ by affine open subsets, you're taking intersections of affine open subsets of $X$ with $Z$.

Per the comments, this question comes from a Hartshorne problem that sets out to show that every subscheme structure on $Z$ has the form $\operatorname{Spec}(A/\mathfrak a)$ with $\sqrt {\mathfrak{ a}} = \mathcal I$. Note that one cannot give meaning to the phrase "affine open subspace of $Z$" without a specified scheme structure on $Z$, but one can say that $Z$ is quasi-compact as a topological space.

Comment: I see, that would make sense. This whole thing is actually part of an attempt to show that every closed subscheme structure on a closed subset of an affine arises from an ideal of $A$. To do this, I've been told that I first need to show that the closed subset has a finite affine cover given by intersections of affines in $A$ with $Z$. 

So does this mean that the intersections $D(f) \cap Z$ can be affine in $Z$ without being affine in $\text{Spec }A$?

Comment: @Luke Hm, I'm guessing you're supposed to show that a closed subscheme has a finite open affine cover - I don't think you can ask that question about the abstract set $Z$ without a scheme structure already on it.

Comment: @Luke Oh, I understand now! You're supposed to show that $Z$ is quasi-compact as a topological space, and since a subscheme structure on $Z$ by definition has an open cover by affine subspaces, it must in particular have a finite subcover by affine subspaces.

Comment: That would make a lot of sense given the hint I am given for the exercise. Thank you very much! I am trying to do exercise 3.11(b) of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry by the way, if you had any other pointers.

Comment: @Luke Very good! Reading it now, I think the intended meaning of the hint is exactly what I said up there - just a bit poorly phrased, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you, that is actually really helpful and it's given me a few new ideas to try.

Comment: @Luke Glad to help! You should accept the answer.